# Did I solve the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} (\ln(x) \cdot \ln(1-x))$ correctly?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

$\lim_{x \to 1} (\ln(x) \cdot \ln(1-x))$
I tried variable changing to change the limit to $\infty$ and then using the common limit $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$$ as below:

$x=X + 1 \implies \lim_{X \to 0} (\ln(X+1)\cdot\ln(-X))$

Then

$X = 1/y \implies \lim_{y \to \infty} (\ln((1/y)+1)\cdot\ln(-1/y))$

Then I multiplied and divided by $(\frac{1}{y}+1)$ and $(\frac{-1}{y})$

And then I had this

$\lim_{y \to \infty} ((1/y)+1)(-1/y)\cdot\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{y}+1)}{\frac{1}{y}+1}\cdot\frac{\ln(\frac{-1}{y})}{\frac{-1}{y}}=0$

Did I do it right?
Note: I knew the limit was 0 before I tried to solve it so it explains why I did these precise steps.

Comment: Note that $x\to 1^-$ and hence $X\to 0^-$ and hence $y\to-\infty$.

Comment: Also I don't see how you plan to use $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1/x)\log x=0$. Rather you should be using $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log x=0$. The desired limit in this question is $0$.

Comment: The logarithm of negative numbers doesn't exist... But if you are more careful, you'll see that you take the limit $y\to-\infty$! To avoid this, you might wanna take $X=1-x$ as first replacement.

Comment: @AmmarIbrahim1 In the end, you have $y\to-\infty$, so that $\frac{-1}{y}\to 0^+$; and you want to handle $\lim_{y\to-\infty} \frac{\ln(-1/y)}{(-1/y)}$. Since $(-1/y)\to 0^+$, not to $\infty$, you can't use $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}$ directly.

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $t=1-x$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-} \log(x)\log(1-x) = 
\lim_{t\to 0^+} \log(1-t)\log(t)
= \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\cdot t\log(t)
$$
If you know that the following two (standard) limits exist, and what they are:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t} \quad \text{ and } \quad \lim_{t\to 0^+} t\log t,
$$
then you can conclude.

Comment: Note that the second is equivalent to $\lim_{u\to+\infty} \frac{\log u}{u}=0$, by setting $u=1/t$.

Comment: I got it. I just took some time to figure out how you did go from $\log(x)$ to $\log(1+t)$ while it's $\log(1-t)$ then I realised it's the same thing when $t \to 0^{+}$. Thank you.

Comment: That's a typo, thanks for spotting it (doesn't change the result, but still.) @AmmarIbrahim1